# What exactly does the update() method does (given that the if condition is giving an empty dictionary)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I don't understand what the dict_dictionary does to the email_ctx dictionary here, does it stay empty of is it overriding some data here?

```
class EmailTemplateContext(Context):
    @staticmethod
    def make_link(path):
        return settings.MAILING_LIST_LINK_DOMAIN + path

    def __init__(self, subscriber, dict_=None, **kwargs):
        if dict_ is None:
            dict_ = {}

        email_ctx = self.common_context(subscriber)
        email_ctx.update(dict_)
        super().__init__(email_ctx, **kwargs)

    def common_context(self, subscriber):
        subscriber_pk_kwargs = {'pk': subscriber.id}
        unsubscribe_path = reverse(
            'mailing_list:unsubscribe',
            kwargs=subscriber_pk_kwargs,
        )
        return {
            'subscriber':subscriber,
            'mailing_list': subscriber.mailing_list,
            'unsubscribe_link': self.make_link(unsubscribe_path),
        }
```

Comment: It may not be empty (if you initialise `EmailTemplateContext` with a non-empty `dict_`), in which case it's added to `email_ctx`. If it's empty, `email_ctx` is just unchanged.

Comment: It's not just added to `email_ctx` but updating any properties already present. So yes, it could override some data.

Comment: correct, my bad for using "adding". See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

Comment: @dirkgroten cool explanation I get it

Comment: @Fnechz some methodology might help:  1/ read the code of the `self.common_context` method and find out what type of object it returns, 2/ then read the doc for this type's `update` method, 3/ eventually laucnh your Python shell, import this type (if it's not builtin), and experiment with it's update method to make sure you fully understood the doc. This doesn't take much more time than positing a question here, and the answer WILL be correct (which is far from garanteed here alas).

Comment: @Fnechz thanks for the updated code. So, you already knew this function returned a dict, so why didn't you just read the doc for `dict.update` directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

email_ctx.update(dict_) will update email_ctx with value of dict_. if dict_={} then noting will update on email_ctx. this is how it will work:

```
>>> email_ctx = { 'name': 'trump', 'age': 60}
>>> dict_ = { 'country': 'USA'} 
>>> email_ctx.update(dict_)
>>> email_ctx
{'name': 'trump', 'age': 60, 'country': 'USA'}
>>> dict_3 = {'name': 'obama'}
>>> email_ctx.update(dict_3)
>>> email_ctx
{'name': 'obama', 'age': 60, 'country': 'USA'}
>>> dict_4 = {}
>>> email_ctx.update(dict_4)
>>> email_ctx
{'name': 'obama', 'age': 60, 'country': 'USA'}
```